# How to separate set into subsets in Julia?

Tags: julia

There are list of inputs `X` and list of outputs `Y`. Each input can be either `1` success or `0` fail.

```
X = [6 7 8]
Y = [1 1 0]
```

What would be the Julia way to split the inputs `X` into two sets - success and fails?

```
XSuccess = [6 7]
XFails = [8]
```

I can do it with loops, but it seems that there are at least two better ways to solve it - with the **find** function and **list comprehensions**.

Comment: I am not sure if Julia has `partition` function, but you can always apply `filter` twice.

Comment: In the question, `Each input...` should probably be `Each output...`. Additionally, `X = [6 7 8]` should probably be `X = [6,7,8]`, as the former is a 2D matrix and the latter is a 1D vector (which looks more logical).

Comment: Given the fixups in the previous comment. `XSuccess = X[Vector{Bool}(Y)]` and `XFails = X[!Vector{Bool}(Y)]`.

Comment: Finally, if `Y = [1 1 0]` is replaced with `Y = Bool[1,1,0]`, then simply `XSuccess = X[Y]` and `XFail = X[!Y]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
XSuccess = getindex(X,find(Y))
XFail = getindex(X, find(x->x==0,Y))
```

Check [the docs](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/arrays/#indexing-assignment-and-concatenation) on array indexing

Answer (score 2):

As you point out, there are a few ways you could do this. Let's look at the `find()` function approach first, and then we'll look at the list comprehension approach.

```julia
x = [6, 7, 8]
y = [1, 1, 0]
xsucc = x[find(y .== 1)]
xfail = x[find(y .== 0)]
```

For the list comprehension approach we could do something like the following.

```julia
x = [6, 7, 8]
y = [1, 1, 0]
xsucc = [w for w in x[y .== 1]]
xfail = [w for w in x[y .== 0]]
```

Of these, I'm not sure which is considered the most idiomatic Julia code (perhaps neither).

Comment: `find` can be avoided and replaced with just `x[y .== 1]`, which has better performance and less memory overhead the larger the amount of hits in the mask.